# Form is not submitting php and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

(Formatted Properly now) .... 
I have form as below:

```
<form style="padding:10px" id="myform" action="http://localhost/web/donedetails" method="post">
    <div class="row half no-collapse-1">
     <div class="6u">
        <label><em>*</em> Your Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="6u">
           <label><em>*</em> Your Email:</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>
    </div>
   <button type="submit" class="rate" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and i am validating form as below:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){                                                                 
  $('#name,#email').keyup(function(){
        if($('#name').val().length !=0){
            $("#name").css("border-color","#CCC");
        }
        if($('#email').val().length !=0){
            $("#email").css("border-color","#CCC");
        }
    });
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        if( name.length == 0){
            $('#name').css("border-color","red");
            }
        if( email.length == 0){
            $('#email').css("border-color","red");
        }
        if(name.length != 0 && email.length != 0 ){
            $("#myform").submit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

While submit, form is not going to `donedetails` page. On clicking `submit`, again same page is returned on which i am currently.

Note: `donedetails` is a php page, i have written done details only as i have prohibited direct `.php` access to files.

Please help to resolve it

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: Yes..no errors at all at console :(

Comment: This works _[just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/rmFg9/)_ Check if you have the jQuery library called.

Comment: open the same path in browser and see

Comment: tried same.. and path just works fine by typing in URL address bar

Comment: Also, instead of using `$("#submit").click()` use `$("#myform").submit()` that way, when you press `enter` it'll go through your code. Oh and of course, `return false;` if invalid, otherwise just `return`.

Comment: did you got solution for this or not

Comment: No @ Karthick Kumar Ganesh ... not yet

Comment: check this fiddle it working http://jsfiddle.net/8wwMN/

Comment: fiddles r wrkng.. bt nt my code :(

Comment: please change this to  <button type="submit" class="rate" id="nosubmit">Save</button>  and try also other references to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured out the problem... and it just drove me crazy :)  .... how my code can nt work.

The problem was that there were two `form` tags.. and somehow i missed to close the first `form` tag..

so the button was submitting only the first `form` with blank action which is true :)

Finally, debugged the code and got the problem .... pheww.... just a small mistake and big impact it was

Answer (score 0):

Ok, instead of complicating the comment. Let I'll post an answer with the code change I suggested.

```
$(document).ready(function(){                                                                 
  $('#name,#email').keyup(function(){
        if($('#name').val().length !=0){
            $("#name").css("border-color","#CCC");
        }
        if($('#email').val().length !=0){
            $("#email").css("border-color","#CCC");
        }
    });

    $('#myform').submit(function(){
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        if(!name ){ // this is enough to check empty string, undefined etc.
            $('#name').css("border-color","red");
        }
        if( !email ){
            $('#email').css("border-color","red");
        }
        if(name && email){
         return;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: also, check your browser's developer console (F12) for errors, server response etc.

Comment: by this,.. the do not validate fields :(

Comment: that's weird, did you check the console? Does it show anything?

Comment: Console has only warning ::
The character encoding of a framed document was not declared. The document may appear different if viewed without the document framing it.

Comment: And, did you check it after clicking/submitting? (console should be active while clicking/submitting.)

Comment: So, the form is submitting properly, but not validating now? Could you please check and verify if there are no other elements on the page with the same ID as `name` or `email`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51799/discussion-between-xfortyfourx-and-gagandeep-sharma)

Answer (score 0):

Well I think that you must put an file extension for action script, because it decides which handler will be chosen at server-side.

Comment: Then try to remove script from html and check if submit will go to donedetails. Also try to call http://localhost/web/donedetails manually in browser.